# POST request from Google Sheets to Norbert API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets

I have create automations with Zapier that get prospect informations and write it in new rows in a spreadsheet. 
This new sheet is composed by :

column A : name

Column B: domain

I want to call an API that gets email : "Voilà Norbert" , and returns the email (or the error) into the Column C.

The Norbert API works as follow:

- Make a POST request to https://www.voilanorbert.com/api/v1/
- With three parameters : name, domain and token

  It return JSON format with the email or an error

I have installed the importJSON code gist.github.com/chrislkeller/5719258 .
I have tried to use the Zapier WebHook, it works, but I can't write the result in my spreadsheet. 
I have tried to use this script https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293  in the google script, but it does not work because I don't know where to put the API URL that is need to be called.

Do you know how to call a POST API with parameters in google spreadsheet that search the parameters into the spreadsheet, and that put the JSON result into the spreadsheet

I'm not a developper (sadly). I think it could be useful for everybody that need to enrich their data into google spreadsheet using API call with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Apps Script code bound to your spreadsheet.  gs code runs on Google's Servers.  In order to communicate with the Norbert API (Or any API), you must use the `UrlFetchApp` class.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

And in particular, the `fetch()` method:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)